# Preventing calling a parent function when clicking on a child node

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code :

```
<li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast"  >
   <div class="Root"><div class="rtTop" onclick="changeActiveView('1')" >
    <span class="rtSp"></span>
    <span class="rtPlus"  onclick="ExpandRoot(this,'SubMenu_1','RootElemUl')"></span>
    <span class='rtIn'>
     <img src='img1.png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <span class='labl'  >Title</span>
   </span>
   </div></div>

   </li>
```

when i click on the span with class`rtPlus` ChangeActiveView is automatically executed as well how can i prevent that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation();`

Prevents further propagation of the current event.

http://devdocs.io/dom/event.stoppropagation

Put that line of JS in the function you want to work, and it will prevent the event from bubbling upward through the DOM and reaching the parent element (and triggering the parent's listener).

Comment: in wish function should i use it ?